# Burning Rubber Smell

Tags: engine, chevrolet, coolant, leak, smell

I have a 2015 Chevy Trax. Recently I have noticed that when the car is idling it smells like burning rubber and will only happen after about 10 mins of driving. Living in northern Ontario I warm my car up before I leave my house and no smell but i Drive for 10 mins and the smell will come when I stop at a red light or when in park. I have brought it to the dealership twice and they cannot find anything wrong with it. Is there cause for concern?

Comment: Car smells are pretty distinct. Leaking coolant (which you seem to be concerned about) has a smell, but it's not like burning rubber IMO.  Have you checked your other liquids (engine oil, etc.)?

Comment: The dealership checked all the fluids and said they are fine and can't seem to figure out where its coming from. I noticed when it started that there was a small amount of pink fluid and because of turbo issues a few months ago made me think it could be another issue with that. They advised it was due to the cold weather and wait it out.

Comment: OK, a small oil leak could be pretty smelly, but not necessarily detectable on the dipstick.  Good luck keep warm.